# Comparing two list by elements (they don't have to be in the same order)

Tags: c++, list, compare

```cpp
int main(){

    ListItem *A=NULL;
    ListItem *B=NULL;
    ListItem *Diffrent=NULL;
    
    std::ifstream file("liczby.txt", std::fstream::in);
    bool write=1;
    int x;
    while(file >> x){
        if(write){
            Add(&A, x);
        }
        else
            Add(&B, x);
        write=!write;
    }
    
    std::cout << "List A: " << std::endl;
    Print(&A);
    std::cout << Sep() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "List B: " << std::endl;
    Print(&B);
    std::cout << Sep() << std::endl;
    
    ListItem *tmp=A;
    while(tmp!=NULL){
        if(Identical(A, B)){
            Add(&Diffrent, A->data);
        }
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    
    std::cout << "List diffrent: " << std::endl;
    Print(&Diffrent);
    std::cout << Sep() << std::endl;
    
    delete A;
    delete B;
    delete Diffrent;
    return 0;
    
    }
    
    int Identical(ListItem *A, ListItem *B){
    while(A!=NULL and B!=NULL){
        if(A->data != B->data){
            return A->data;
        }
        A=A->next;
        B=B->next;
        }
        return (A==NULL and B==NULL);
    }
```

I am trying to compare to list A and list B if they have the same element (order is not required). If the element isn't in both list, I have to write the element to other list Different.

The problem is that, program is comparing only the first element from list A with all elements from list B. The list Different is full with the first element of list A.

Comment: No, the shown code does not appear to compare "only the first element from list A with all elements from list B", it's doing something else. It's still not the described task, but that's what it is. It is completely unclear, though, what your question is. You forgot to mention something very, very important in your Stackoverflow question. That would be a question. A very careful search of the shown question reveals a description of a programming task, followed by some code. That's it. But no question. What is your question?

Comment: After sorting the two lists, [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) might help.